# how to get number from the id value?

Tags: jquery

I've the following html:

```
<button type="button" id="step-1">step1</button>
<button type="button" id="step-2">step2</button>
<button type="button" id="step-3">step3</button>
<button type="button" id="step-4">step4</button>
```

And I want to get the number from id like 1,2,3,4. So using like this:

```
$('[id^=step]').on('click',function(){
    var stepbg = parseInt($(this).attr('id'),10);alert(stepbg);
});
```

But it's alerting NaN. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avW3h/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$(this).attr('id')` you can simply use `this.id`.

try like this,

```
$('[id^=step]').on('click', function () {
    var stepbg = parseInt(this.id.replace(/\D/g, ''));
    alert(stepbg);
});
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/ZPqTs/)**</kbd>

Comment: this won't work if the number gets to length greater than 1 digit

Answer (score 1):

you can achive that using `split()`

```
$('[id^=step]').on('click',function(){
    var stepbg = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split("-")[1],10);alert(stepbg);
});
```

Also you can use replace function as well

```
$('[id^=step]').on('click',function(){
    var stepbg = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('step-',''));  alert(stepbg);
});
```

here is another regular expression example

```
 $('[id^=step]').on('click',function(){
var stepbg = parseInt($(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/)[0], 10);  alert(stepbg);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple regex to extract the last set of digits from the `id`

```
var stepbg = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0], 10);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6B9Kj/)

Comment: I don't understand the regex way, can you please give this me another way?

Comment: This searches the id for `\d` which is any digit and `+` which is 1-infinite times.

Answer (score 0):

> Use split() in jquery.

```
    $('[id^=step]').on('click',function(){
    var stepbg = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split("-")[1] ,10);
        alert(stepbg);
   });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ehG2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the string in the id with empty string you do not want and get the number out of it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avW3h/3/)**

```
$('[id^=step]').on('click',function(){
    var stepbg = parseInt(this.id.replace('step-',''));  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try **`split()`** this:

```
    arr = $(this).attr('id').split('-');//split to array
    stepbg = parseInt(arr[arr.length-1]); //get last element
    alert(stepbg);
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/avW3h/4/)

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avW3h/2/)

***Description:** this is quick and dirty, I recommend using regex or split to get a better working example for production.*

```
$('[id^=step]').on('click',function(){
    var stepbg = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(5), 10);
    alert(stepbg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code given below:

```
   $('[id^=step]').on('click',function(){
    var id =$(this).attr('id').replace(/step-/, '');
    alert(id)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^=step]').on('click',function(){
    var stepbg = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    alert(stepbg[1]);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/avW3h/5/)